# MySQL query SELECT FROM 2 tables, COUNT the most used

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have this 2 tables and I need to return the moset used office. Note: 1 office can be used by more than 1 guys and the column ido from TableB is populate from TableA

Probaly is a query with `group by` and `desc` `limit 1`

TableA

```
| ido|  office | guy |
---------------------
|  1 |  office1| guy1|
|  2 |  office2| guy2|
|  3 |  office1| guy3|
|  4 |  office1| guy4|
|  5 |  office5| guy5|
|  6 |  office2| guy6|
```

TableB

```
 | idb|  vizit  | ido|
 ---------------------
 |  1 |  date   | 4  |
 |  2 |  date   | 2  |
 |  3 |  date   | 5  |
 |  4 |  date   | 6  |
 |  5 |  date   | 1  |
 |  6 |  date   | 6  |
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were correct in that GROUP BY, LIMIT and DESC are useful here; it leads to a fairly straight forward query;

```
SELECT TableA.office 
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB
  ON TableA.ido = TableB.ido
GROUP BY TableA.office
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

What it does is basically create rows with all valid combinations, counting the number of generated rows per office. A plain descending sort by that count will give you the most frequently used office.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1763d/1).

Comment: It return a line from TableA, i need only the most used office. Thanks for the support! Jens's solution worked.

Comment: @Blueleaf Changed the query to only return the most frequently visited office.

Comment: Works better! Thanks a lot!